# Java Cipher NoSuchPaddingException

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I'm not very experienced with Java, so this may be a nooby question. I was trying to experiment a bit with Java encryption, but for some reason I can't get an instance of `Cipher`. I always get a [`NoSuchPaddingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/NoSuchPaddingException.html) on this line, changing the padding to something else, like `"/NoPadding"` doesn't work:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Trying to run the code even though Eclipse says it's wrong results in this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
Unhandled exception type NoSuchPaddingException

at Encryption.main(Encryption.java:10)
```

What could be the problem? Do I have to import some certain things? In the current code I `import javax.crypto.Cipher` and `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec`.

When I use Jython the code works by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exceptions that have been extended from `GeneralSecurityException`, including `NoSuchPaddingException` and `NoSuchAlgorithmException` are checked exceptions. Checked exceptions are exceptions that **must** be handled in Java. You can handle exceptions in multiple ways:

1. Add a `throws` clause to your method;
2. Catch it and wrap a `RuntimeException` around it, using the original as cause (basically upgrading the exception in such a way that does not have to be handled, normally resulting in application failure);
3. Catch it, do something useful with it and simply move on.

In general, for `NoSuchAlgorithmException` and `NoSuchPaddingException` you upgrade the exception to a `RuntimeException` such as `IllegalStateException`. Normally your algorithm string stays static, and Java runtime environments are required to support `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` so this exception only occurs if something is terribly wrong.

You can either catch `GeneralSecurityException` or use a multi catch clause if you don't want to handle these exceptions separately. `BadPaddingException` and `IllegalBlockSizeException` during the decryption methods indicates a **input** failure and should therefore be handled separately (and keep in mind padding oracle attacks).

Note that Jython, as a different language, does not use checked exceptions so the exceptions simply fall through and cause program failure...

---

Example:

```
try {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
} catch(GeneralSecurityException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not retrieve AES cipher", e);
}
```

Comment: Note that it is relatively dumb that these kind of exceptions are checked exceptions precisely because they are normally not dependent on input or runtime state. In other words, they *should* have been `RuntimeException`s instead of checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The method which you are using throws Exception,so you need to handle that using `try` `catch` blocks,

use,

```
try{
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
}

catch(Exception e){
    //print some thing
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, but the other answer goes into more detail and also explains why I have to catch it. After reading this answer I was first confused why I have to try-catch it until I read the other answer.